# The z-axis label is not showing in a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have an issue with a 3d plot, at the moment of visualizing it. It appears without the z-axis label,

[image]

but when I set a longer title, it appears:

[image]

Is there any way to be able to "see" the z-axis label without modifying the title or another kind of solution to this issue?

This is my code:

mask1, mask2, mask3 shapes are `(100,100)` with values of 20, 32, 49 respectively

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100)*20, np.arange(100)*20)
s1 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask1*20, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 1')
s1._facecolors2d = s1._facecolor3d
s1._edgecolors2d = s1._edgecolor3d
s2 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask2*20, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 2')
s2._facecolors2d = s2._facecolor3d
s2._edgecolors2d = s2._edgecolor3d
s3 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask3*20, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 3')
s3._facecolors2d = s3._facecolor3d
s3._edgecolors2d = s3._edgecolor3d

ax.set(xlim=[0, 2000], ylim=([0, 2000]), zlim=([1000, 0]),
       xlabel=(r' $x [m]$'), ylabel=(r'$y [m]$'), zlabel=(r'$z [m]$'))

ax.legend()
ax.set_title('a short title', fontsize=18)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zoom out a bit to make the label visible. E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100)*20, np.arange(100)*20)
mask =  np.ones(x.shape)
s1 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask*400, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 1')
s1._facecolors2d = s1._facecolor3d
s1._edgecolors2d = s1._edgecolor3d
s2 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask*700, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 2')
s2._facecolors2d = s2._facecolor3d
s2._edgecolors2d = s2._edgecolor3d
s3 = ax.plot_surface(x, y, mask*1000, linewidth=0, label='Reflector 3')
s3._facecolors2d = s3._facecolor3d
s3._edgecolors2d = s3._edgecolor3d


ax.set(xlim=[0, 2000], ylim=([0, 2000]), zlim=([1000, 0]),
   xlabel=(r' $x [m]$'), ylabel=(r'$y [m]$'), zlabel=(r'$z [m]$'))

ax.legend()
ax.set_title('a short title', fontsize=18)
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Which creates this plot:
[image: plot]

Comment: It is still unsettling that there is so much white space on the left of the figure. Also, I found that if you zoom out, the box containing the legends moves further away from the figure.

Comment: @zltn.guba, yes this is a downside, What you could do (although it is not nice) is to make the fig size `(15,5)` (x1.25). Then, the `0.8` zoom should restore the legend size. Then save the image and crop it out. This however has the disadvantage of de-centering the headline...

Comment: this used to work no problem on matplotlib 3.5.2. What went wrong in the newer versions of matplotlib? Are they going to fix this bug?