# z-axis label is not shown on figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, matplotlib-3d

When trying to make a 3D plot, the label on the z-axis is never shown, only when I adjust the labelpad by hand. I find this solution extremely annoying, because I see no reason why it is not possible to add more whitespace to the figure.

I demonstrate my problem using a code snippet from [this source](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-2dcollections3d-py)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Plot a sin curve using the x and y axes.
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi) / 2 + 0.5
ax.plot(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='curve in (x, y)')

# Plot scatterplot data (20 2D points per colour) on the x and z axes.
colors = ('r', 'g', 'b', 'k')

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x = np.random.sample(20 * len(colors))
y = np.random.sample(20 * len(colors))
c_list = []
for c in colors:
    c_list.extend([c] * 20)
# By using zdir='y', the y value of these points is fixed to the zs value 0
# and the (x, y) points are plotted on the x and z axes.
ax.scatter(x, y, zs=0, zdir='y', c=c_list, label='points in (x, z)')

# Make legend, set axes limits and labels
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Customize the view angle so it's easier to see that the scatter points lie
# on the plane y=0
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-35, roll=0)

plt.show()
```

The expected outcome for this code is shown on the cited source. What I get is shown below [image: Outcome of the code snippet]

As you see, everything is correctly placed, however, the label on z-axis is totally missing. Is there any solution to this problem besides moving the label closer to the z-axis?

I am aware of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804827/the-z-axis-label-is-not-showing-in-a-3d-plot), however, I want to avoid having that much whitespace on the left-hand side of the figure.

Comment: Increasing the figure size, `ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10)).add_subplot(projection='3d')`, didn't resolve the issue, but `ax.zaxis._axinfo['juggled'] = (1, 2, 2)` is a workaround. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRqsy.png) in `matplotlib v3.7.1`

Comment: alternatively, this used to work fine in matplotlib 3.5.2, so you could downgrade. I'm not sure what went wrong in the newer versions. Hopefully they will fix it...